# "&" always returns false

Tags: c#, foreach

I want to check if a certain value in an array is less than 10 and greater than 1. Problem is that when I run my code, it always returns -1, as in the following example. What am I doing wrong?

```
int[] note = new int[5] {2, 3, 4, 5};
foreach (int element in note)
{
    if(element <= 10 & element >= 0)
        suma = suma + element;
    else    
        return -1;
}
```

Comment: I think we either need a working example or the real code of your problem to find your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You just forgot the return of suma. Till then the only way to leave the function was by returning -1.

Also **it will return -1 if one single element doesnt match your condition**.

```
    int[] note = new int[4] {2, 3, 4, 5}; 

    int suma = 0;

    foreach (int element in note)
    {
        if (element <= 10 & element >= 0)
            suma = suma + element;
        // You may want to remove the following part
        else    
            return -1; 
    }

    return suma; // This was missing
```

Here is the Fiddle of your code running without the -1
https://dotnetfiddle.net/t3uL1G

You can also use Linq to only sum all the elements that match your condition like this:

```
using System.Linq; 
...
int suma = note.Where(e => e < 11 && e > 0).Sum(); //  + 0 is redundant.
```

Comment: If there's a way to reach the closing `}` of the function without reaching any `return` statement, the C# compiler will give an error message, so it's clear that there is a `return` statement that the OP merely didn't show. But you could be right that it's an incorrect return statement.

Comment: Please reconsider your downvotes here.

Comment: That edit does make it a potential good answer that the OP quite possibly overlooked.

Comment: i dont know why people are downvoting these answers. It makes sense to me. LINQ is the solution to any problem.

Comment: there is nothing to reconsider here you are just making assumptions and I think that the issue is in the example provided by the OP so you should not provide an  answer on something incomplete

Comment: Why is making assumptions bad, either prove them wrong or let op decide whether they are helpful for him or not.

Comment: Who downvotes may not come back to see if you edited your answer and it was initially wrong (missing bold part, even if it's just a supposition it has been discussed first in comments now deleted) so I don't think who downvoted will retract...